# textbox under commandbar of windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-phone-8.1, commandbar

Is it possible to add/include  a `textbox` under  `commandbar` of windows phone 8.1 app as present in Internet Explorer 10..[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you can only use `AppBarButton` and `AppBarToggleButton`.
Apps like IE and the app store where you can see rectangular buttons in the command bar, are special apps in which `Microsoft` can do whathever they want.

But you could try to implement your own custom `CommandBar` that immitates the system command bar, but this seems like too much work and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

**[Yolo](https://github.com/ThomasNigro/Yolo)**

This project aims to create useful controls for WinRT (Windows Phone, Windows 8.1, and later XBOX One). The first one is a customizable AppBar control, which is in a early stage of development.

You can use this app bar to suit your requirements.